# WindowLoaded() not getting called

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, instantiation

I have a breakpoint in a form's OnLoaded event (which dynamically creates some controls), yet when I instantiate the form, it simply sits there looking blanched, and Window_Loaded() is never called.

I instantiate the form with a custom constructor:

```
NoUseForAName nufan = new NoUseForAName(iListMsgTypes, dtFrom, dtTo);
nufan.Show();
```

And have added the Loaded() event, which I expect to get called directly after I call .Show() on the form:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Why is [Window_]Loaded() not getting reached?

Comment: Does your Window constructor call `InitializeComponent()` like the default constructor does?

Comment: No; I was wondering about that, and will now add it/test it.

Comment: That was it - adding InitializeComponent() to my custom constructor solved the problem. But: I added "InitializeComponent()" as the first line of the custom constructor; is that where it should be? Does location matter in this instance ([no] pun intended)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either add

```
InitializeComponent();
```

as the first line of your custom constructor, or call the default constructor like this:

```
public NoUseForAName(...)
    : this()
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you hook up the event anywhere? e.g. on the new instance

```
nufan.Loaded += Window_Loaded;
```

(Also loaded is not called *"directly"* after show, loading may take a while)

Comment: Is there a better place to put my dynamic control creation code than Loaded()? The constructor was too soon - is Loaded() too late?

Comment: @ClayShannon: I don't think so, loaded ensures that your other controls are there so if you named controls you can access them via the fields. But i think there actually should not be any "dynamic control creation" to begin with, what stops you from using [data templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) and the like to create dynamic content?

Comment: That gives me:"The name 'Window_Loaded' does not exist in the current context"

The code I added between the call to the constructor and the call to Show() is: nufan.Loaded += Window_Loaded;

I have to admit, it does seem strange to me that I would have to specify that the form should call its Loaded() event; that should be automatic, shouldn't it?

Comment: @ClayShannon Put it in the Initialized event. If you don't want to have to add the event handler, override OnInitialized instead of doing a Window_Initialized method. (The same corresponds to Loaded, but Loaded is the wrong event to use. In particular, it is called after the window appears on the screen, and there's no guarantee (though it likely won't happen for a Window) of it not being called more than once)

Comment: @Random749: Once I added "InitializeComponent" it works fine; however I will try moving the code from the Loaded() event to Initialized() event.

Comment: Moving my code from Loaded() to Initialized() gave me, "System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code"
on this line:   bGetDebug = _logMsgTypeIntList.Contains(LogParsePumpViewerConsts.LOG_MSG_TYPE_DEBUG);

Comment: @ClayShannon: As i said, in loaded you can be sure that all references are set.